# How to fix this 'UnicodeEncodeError'/'TypeError' when reading text for LSTM in Keras

Tags: python, keras

I am using the code [here by the keras team](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/lstm_text_generation.py) for text generation using LSTMs, but I use my own text data. I get this error when running on GPU.

I figured we need to use 'utf-8' but that's already specified when reading from the text file.

```
path = 'path/to/mytxt.txt'
with io.open(path, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text = f.read().lower()
```

I don't understand where the problem is coming from.Rest of the code is exactly the same. Part where error comes :

```
def on_epoch_end(epoch, _):
    # Function invoked at end of each epoch. Prints generated text.

    start_index = random.randint(0, len(text) - maxlen - 1)
    for diversity in [0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 1.2]:

        generated = ''
        sentence = text[start_index: start_index + maxlen]
        generated += sentence
        print('----- Generating with seed: "' + sentence + '"')
```

Error :

> File "txt_gen.py", line 77, in on_epoch_end
>
> print('----- Generating with seed: "' + sentence + '"')
>
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u201c' in position 65: ordinal not in range(128)

UPDATE :

Tried `print('----- Generating with seed: "' + sentence.encoded('utf-8') + '"')` and now the error changed to

> TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly

Comment: Are there any Emojis in your data?

Comment: Also consider using `text.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: It looks like your terminal does not support UTF-8.

Comment: No emojis. Please see update. @IrfanuddinShafi

Comment: @KlausD. But it ran for 1 epoch perfectly. Please see update, the error changed to TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly

Comment: You want to print a unicode quotation mark. Your terminal does not support that. I can't tell you what has changed.